# Set number of decimal places to 0 if float is an integer (java)?

Tags: java, floating-point, integer, decimal

I'm using a float to hold a score. The score can be an integer or decimal. By default, floats display as 0.0, 1.0, etc. If the number does not have a decimal, I need it to display as 0, 1, etc. If it does have a decimal, then I need to display the decimal. How might I do this?

Comment: You shouldn't use a float to hold a score. It's prone to cumulative errors. I suggest using two variables to hold the two parts of the score, and then simply formatting the display of the score appropriately.

Comment: Or use a [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Comment: It has to be a float because SharedPreferences accepts floats, not doubles (Android, btw)

Answer (score 3):

```
String string;
float n = 3.0f;
if (n % 1 == 0) {
    string = String.valueOf((int) n);
} else {
    string = String.valueOf(n);
}
System.out.println("Score: " + string);
```

<strike>Warning: Untested code. ;)</strike>

Ok, I've tested it and fixed an error.

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
NumberFormat.getInstance().format(score);
```

to display with decimal places when present.

To counter against rounding errors, `score` here could be represented using a [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Comment: This didn't get rid of the decimal though?

Comment: Dont display the raw score, use the output from NumberFormat.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to work out the smallest granularity of score and then use that with an appropriate multiplier.

For example, if the smallest increment is 0.01, use a multiplier of 100. And if your score % mulitplier = 0 then you know its a whole number.

That way you dont need to worry about rounding, or representation errors.