# Format float to show decimal places if is not zero java

Tags: java, regex, floating-point, decimalformat

I need to to show decimal places of a float value only when it is different from zeros.

1. **5.0** should be shown as **5**.
2. **7.3** should be shown as **7.3**.
3. **9.000003** should be shown as **9.000003**.

How to format in this way using regex or DecimalFormat?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12045199/4101906)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To display decimals the way you desire, use the following snippet:

```
// This is to show symbol . instead of ,
DecimalFormatSymbols otherSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US);
// Define the maximum number of decimals (number of symbols #)
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##########", otherSymbols);

// type: double
System.out.println(df.format(5.0)); // writes 5
System.out.println(df.format(7.3)); // writes 7.3
System.out.println(df.format(9.000003)); // writes 9.000003

// type: float
System.out.println(df.format(9.000003f)); // writes 9.000002861
```